# How to wire a button

Tags: raspbian, led, gpiozero

O have tried to do this so many times, so many websites, so many books, and it just won't work. I do not know how to wire it so that the LED lights up when I press the  button. I'm pretty sure that I have the correct type of button, and it works when I only tell it to just light the LED, so I am so confused.

Here is one of the more recent codes I have used.

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause 
led = LED(18)
button = Button(23)  
button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off

pause()
```

Here is the wiring I used.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There you go, my real wiring. -_-

Comment: Does it work if you do the following `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs pud 23 u` and then press the button?

Comment: @joan no it does not, should I buy new buttons or wires? Why is this not working? Really appreciate you guy's help

Comment: In that case you have not wired as shown in the schematic.  Edit your question and provide clear photos allowing us to follow the connections.

Comment: A quick test is to run [./monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) and see if there are any button presses (ignore GPIO 28/29).

Comment: @Joan I did it joan all my real wiring

Comment: @joanhow do I run monitor.py?

Comment: @joan it worked but it was empty even after I ran the code again and pressed the button multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Raspberry Pi 3 then try this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Setting BCM mode
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Setting Button Input with Pull down Resistor notation
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    try:
        if (GPIO.input(4)==0): # Cheking Button Condition
            print("Button 1 Pressed")
            GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            print("Push Button")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        sys.exit()
time.sleep(1)
```

For Connection wiring take reference from this:
http://www.toptechboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/raspberry-pi-LEDs.jpg

And if you like to follow this:
https://www.hackster.io/hardikrathod/push-button-with-raspberry-pi-6b6928

Comment: Just asking, did it work for you?

Comment: Because so many things have not worked, I don't exactly have much faith in the internet, so did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: Yes...it is working great. Sorry for the late reply.
I was using two buttons with the raspberry pi and controlled the 2 respective LEDs.